# Extract part of string in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, string

I have this string

```
<p><img src="http://www.foo.com/bar.jpg"></p><p>other content here</p>
```

I need to extract the src url . The img tag appears only at the beggining of the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use a regular expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  :-)

Comment: ...seriously, look at the XML classes in the documentation and parse it as XML, then look up the img child element and get the value of the src attribute.

Comment: This is inside a third party json file which i have no access...

Comment: XML parsers wouldn't work on that particular string, since it's invalid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.split:

```
var s:String = "<p><img src=\"http://www.foo.com/bar.jpg\"></p><p>other content here</p>";
var a:Array = s.split('"');
```

The src url would be the 2nd element of the array, so:

```
trace(a[1]);
```